# Mysql : foreign key relative to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I'm trying to improve the database integrity adding some foreign key (it's the first time i use them).

I have some tables relative to different type of **devices** (different tables because the "devices" are completely different from each other), a table **groups** and a relation-table **group_device** (the same device can be in more groups).

---

**devices_typeA**

*id is primary key*

```
id | column1 | column2 | 
------------------------
1  | aaa     | bbbb    |
2  | aaa     | bbbb    |
```

---

**devices_typeB**

*id is primary key*

```
id | column1 | column2 | column2 | columnN | 
--------------------------------------------
1  | aaa     | bbbb    | cccc    | dddd    |
2  | aaa     | bbbb    | cccc    | dddd    |
```

---

**devices_typeC**

*id is primary key*

```
id | column1 | 
--------------
1  | aaa     | 
2  | aaa     |
```

---

**groups**

*id is primary key*

```
id | name    | 
--------------
1  | group 1 | 
2  | group 2 | 
3  | group n |
```

---

**group_device**

```
id | type_device | id_device | id_group |
-----------------------------------------
1  | typeA       | 1         | 1        | 
2  | typeA       | 1         | 2        | 
3  | typeB       | 1         | 1        | 
4  | typeC       | 2         | 3        |
```

---

Now i would like to add some foreign key to the tables **group_device** (in such a way that when a device is deleted, is deleted also in the table **group_device** [with the ON DELETE CASCADE action]). My problem is the id_device column, that is relative to multiple tables (devices_typeA.id, devices_typeB.id , devices_typeC.id).

Answer (score 1):

`FOREIGN KEYs` have severe limitations.  I think you have exceeded them.

Complex data structures cannot depend on FKs for integrity, *your* code is required.

Suggest that you build Stored Routines and/or subroutines in your application language, and encapsulate the integrity constraints there.  And build a clean API into the routines to make it easy for the clients to achieve *their* goals while the *routine* achieves the integrity goals.

Answer (score 1):

A declared foreign key (i.e., one enforced by the database engine) cannot tie to multiple other tables. So `id_device` in `group_device` cannot be a foreign key to all three device tables.

You have a few options:

### Multiple `group_device` tables

Have a unique table linking each type of device to the appropriate group (`group_device_typeA`, `group_device_typeB`, `group_device_typeC`, etc.).

You can create a `group_device` view that's basically the same as the current `group_device` table. You wouldn't have a true `group_device`.`id` column (the other three columns should uniquely identify a row). You could find a way to create a unique ID across the actual `group_device_*` tables if absolutely required, but that's a bit more work.

This does involve a certain amount of maintenance pain - when a new device is added, you have to create two tables (`device_typeN` and `group_device_typeN`), plus you have to modify the `group_device` view.

### Multiple columns in `group_device` (don't use)

You *could* create the `group_device` table with a unique column for each possible device type (`device_typeA_id`, `device_typeB_id`, `device_typeC_id`, etc.). Then, add a trigger (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34141012/3093192)) to ensure that all but one of these values is NULL.

Maintenance requirements are similar to the first suggestion: when a new type is added, you have to create the `device_typeN` table; add the `device_typeN_id` column to the `group_device` table, and modify your trigger.

However, this approach is generally frowned upon. You're trying to use the built-in foreign key mechanism - but you're also trying to work around it. The trigger's code will be repetitive enough that it should be easy to maintain - but it's also easy to screw it up and not notice. And then, you could wind up with rows with multiple ID columns filled in, which is likely to cause some confusion in joins and such (if not outright bad data). It's also easy to have a typo that results in assigning a single `id` value to the wrong column, with similar confusing results.

I mention it more for the sake of completeness than for any other reason.

### Use a "virtual" foreign key

(This is the option that Rick James' answer covers - refer to that for more detail).

Use `group_device` as you have it defined now, where the foreign key is one column that identifies a table (`type_device`) and one that identifies a row in that table (`device_id`). Create code to confirm that the `device_id` is a valid ID from the table in question, and to delete the appropriate `group_device` row if the underlying device is deleted. It's possible this can be done in triggers (insert/update trigger on `group_device` to validate new/changed data; delete trigger on each device table, to check for and remove any `group_device` rows when a device is deleted).

Maintenance should simply be creating the delete trigger when you create the device table, and updating the insert/update trigger on `group_device` to work with the new table.

If using this solution, I recommend that you either use the full table name for `type_device`; have a `type_device` table listing the `device_type*` tables with an ID, and use that ID in `group_device`; or (at a minimum) establish a strict naming convention for `device_typeN` tables, so you know that `CONCAT('device_' + type_device)` will always yield the correct table name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one sketch. Introduce a generic DEVICES table.

```
CREATE TABLE devices
( device_id ... NOT NULL
, device_type ... NOT NULL
, ... -- generice attributes
, PRIMARY KEY (device_id)
, UNIQUE (device_type, device_id)
, CHECK (device_type IN ('A','B','C')) 
);

CREATE TABLE devices_typeA
( device_id ... NOT NULL
, device_type ... NOT NULL
, ... -- type_A specific attributes
, PRIMARY KEY (device_id)
, CHECK (device_type = 'A') -- introduced in 8.0.16
, FOREIGN KEY (device_id, device_type)
      REFERENCES devices (device_id, device_type)
          ON DELETE CASCADE -- I assume
```

Some notes, a FOREIGN KEY can reference a UNIQUE constraint, not only the PRIMARY KEY. That together with CHECK constraint can guarantee that the correct device_type is used in devices.

For MySQL < 8.0.16 CHECK CONSTRAINTS did not exist (introduced SQL92, 199x). Mimic them with ENUM may seem like a good idea at first, DONT!!!, see for example: [how-does-mariadb-handle-enum-types-used-in-foreign-key-constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207540/how-does-mariadb-handle-enum-types-used-in-foreign-key-constraints/207541#207541)

Now GROUP_DEVISES can reference GROUPS as well as DEVICES

```
CREATE TABLE group_devices
( group_id ...
, device_id ...
, PRIMARY KEY (group_id, device_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (group_id) 
      REFERENCES groups (group_id) 
          ON DELETE CASCADE
          ...  
, FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES devices (device_id)
      REFERENCES devices (device_id) 
          ON DELETE CASCADE
          ...
```

If a device is deleted, the delete is cascaded to both device_type... as well as to group_devices.