# confusing error when providing a user defined function with an invalid enum value

Tags: mysql-8.0

I have a function thats called `GET_TRANSLATION` and it can return different results based on different select queries based on the enum value it is provided. Here is the full code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_TRANSLATION(preferredLanguageId BIGINT, backupLanguageId BIGINT, entityId BIGINT, translationSubject ENUM('CROP_NAME', 'CROP_VARIETY_NAME', 'JOURNAL_TITLE', 'SOIL_TYPE', 'COUNTRY', 'PROVINCE', 'PLACE'))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN translationSubject = 'CROP_NAME' THEN
            RETURN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT s.translatedName FROM CropNameTranslation s WHERE s.language_id = preferredLanguageId AND s.parent_id = entityId AND s.approved = TRUE LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT s.translatedName FROM CropNameTranslation s WHERE s.language_id = backupLanguageId AND s.parent_id = entityId AND s.approved = TRUE LIMIT 1), (SELECT s.translatedName FROM CropNameTranslation s WHERE s.parent_id = entityId AND s.approved = TRUE LIMIT 1)));
        WHEN translationSubject = 'CROP_VARIETY_NAME' THEN
            RETURN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT s.translatedName FROM CropVarietyName s WHERE s.language_id = preferredLanguageId AND s.parent_id = entityId AND s.approved = TRUE LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT s.translatedName FROM CropVarietyName s WHERE s.language_id = backupLanguageId AND s.parent_id = entityId AND s.approved = TRUE LIMIT 1), (SELECT s.translatedName FROM CropVarietyName s WHERE s.parent_id = entityId AND s.approved = TRUE LIMIT 1)));
        WHEN translationSubject = 'JOURNAL_TITLE' THEN
            RETURN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT s.title FROM JournalTitleAndContent s WHERE s.language_id = preferredLanguageId AND s.journal_id = entityId LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT s.title FROM JournalTitleAndContent s WHERE s.language_id = backupLanguageId AND s.journal_id = entityId LIMIT 1), (SELECT s.title FROM JournalTitleAndContent s WHERE s.journal_id = entityId LIMIT 1)));
        WHEN translationSubject = 'SOIL_TYPE' THEN
            RETURN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT s.translatedName FROM SoilTypeNameTranslation s WHERE s.language_id = preferredLanguageId AND s.soiltypedetails_id = entityId LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT s.translatedName FROM SoilTypeNameTranslation s WHERE s.language_id = backupLanguageId AND s.soiltypedetails_id = entityId LIMIT 1), (SELECT s.translatedName FROM SoilTypeNameTranslation s WHERE s.soiltypedetails_id = entityId LIMIT 1)));
        WHEN translationSubject = 'COUNTRY' THEN
            RETURN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT ct.translatedName FROM countryNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId AND ct.language_id = preferredLanguageId LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT ct.translatedName FROM countryNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId AND ct.language_id = backupLanguageId LIMIT 1), (SELECT ct.translatedName FROM countryNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId LIMIT 1)));
        WHEN translationSubject = 'PROVINCE' THEN
            RETURN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT ct.translatedName FROM provinceNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId AND ct.language_id = preferredLanguageId LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT ct.translatedName FROM provinceNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId AND ct.language_id = backupLanguageId LIMIT 1), (SELECT ct.translatedName FROM provinceNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId LIMIT 1)));
        WHEN translationSubject = 'PLACE' THEN
            RETURN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT ct.translatedName FROM placeNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId AND ct.language_id = preferredLanguageId LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT ct.translatedName FROM placeNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId AND ct.language_id = backupLanguageId LIMIT 1), (SELECT ct.translatedName FROM placeNameTranslation ct WHERE ct.parent_id = entityId LIMIT 1)));
        ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid enumType!';
    END CASE;
END
```

I used this function in a larger select query. IE `SELECT c.scientificName, GET_TRANSLATION(@languageId, 1, j.soiltype_details_id, 'CROP') as soilType FROM journal j;`

I mistakenly gave it the input `CROP` instead of `CROP_NAME`. Now it should have gone in the `else` part of the `CASE` structure and return an error with the message `invalid enumType`. However, What i really get is the error `Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'translationSubject' at row 1`.

My question is; why doesn't it trigger the error that i defined for invalid enum types and why does it treat `translationSubject`as a column that is "truncated" ? This error is completely out of place because the cause is merely a wrong enum value.

Could anyone explain this behavior to me?

Thank you

EDIT:

I just tried changing SIGNAL to RESIGNAL and removing the SQLSTATE parameter. Furthermore I've added

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        RESIGNAL;
    END;
```

to GET_TRANSLATION but the same error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the parameter to text:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION GET_TRANSLATION(translationSubject TEXT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    CASE WHEN translationSubject = 'CROP_NAME' THEN
             RETURN 'dummy';
         ELSE 
             SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid enumType!';
    END CASE;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

it will behave as you expect

```
SELECT GET_TRANSLATION('CROP_NAME');
'dummy'

SELECT GET_TRANSLATION('CROP');
Query Error: Error: ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION: Invalid enumType!
```

If you use an enum, the error occurs before the function body is evaluated

Comment: could you explain to me what it is about ENUM that is causing that strange error? What does data truncation have to do with a wrong enum value?

Comment: Not really, I'm not very experienced with Mysql so I dont know where the error is generated. I tried with other datatypes to clarify, but the problem is that MYSQL converts types in strange ways. I guess that an enum is one of the cases where it can not.

Comment: BTW, enum in MySQL have som counter-intuitive behaviour, see for example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207540/how-does-mariadb-handle-enum-types-used-in-foreign-key-constraints . Since you are using MySQL 8 I suggest that you use check constraints instead of enums.