# Filter and Aggregate a column not in the group by clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, group-by

I have the following table. I'm using mysql-5.7. Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dc909da120f2a346366ae952e40192d5)

```
select * from report;
+----+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------+------+-------------------+
| id | date_hour           | speed   | name | nor  | validation | p_i  | speed_performance |
+----+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------+------+-------------------+
|  1 | 2018-02-03 13:23:00 |   -12.3 | SYN  |   10 | 1          | 3    | 4                 |
|  2 | 2018-02-03 11:23:00 |   -6.36 | SYN  |   13 | 0          | 4    | 5                 |
|  3 | 2018-02-03 01:23:00 |  -26.36 | SYN  |   24 | 0          | 2    | 4                 |
|  4 | 2020-04-06 21:23:00 | -156.36 | SYN  |   16 | 1          | 3    | 6                 |
|  5 | 2020-04-06 03:23:00 |  -36.36 | YRT  |  136 | 0          | 2    | 5                 |
|  6 | 2020-04-06 12:23:00 |  -16.36 | SYN  |   13 | 1          | 4    | 4                 |
+----+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------+------+-------------------+
```

I would like to `group by` `date_hour` such that after `12:00:00`, it counts as the next day. The `p_i` column should be averaged based on this condition: take `average` of `p_i` where `validation` is 1 and `p_i` is non-zero. The values should be averaged based on the new version of `date_hour`. Additionally, another column (`nor`) is averaged without such a condition.

The output should look like this

```
+------+------------+----------+------+
| name | date_hr    | avg(nor) | p_i  |
+------+------------+----------+------+
| SYN  | 2018-02-03 |     18.5 | NULL |
| SYN  | 2018-02-04 |       10 |    3 |
| SYN  | 2020-04-07 |     14.5 |  3.5 |
| YRT  | 2020-04-06 |      136 | NULL |
+------+------------+----------+------+
```

I tried the following query. I had to disable `only_full_group_by` to get it to work:

```
select name, 
case when time(date_hour) > '12:00:00' 
then date(date_hour) + interval 1 day 
else date(date_hour) end as date_hr, 
avg(nor), 
case when validation = 1 and p_i > 0 then avg(p_i) else null end as p_i 
from report group by name, date_hr;

+------+------------+----------+------+
| name | date_hr    | avg(nor) | p_i  |
+------+------------+----------+------+
| SYN  | 2018-02-03 |     18.5 |    3 |
| SYN  | 2018-02-04 |       10 | NULL |
| SYN  | 2020-04-07 |     14.5 | NULL |
| YRT  | 2020-04-06 |      136 |    2 |
+------+------------+----------+------+
```

Comment: `I had to disable only_full_group_by to get it to work:` - a query which runs under that condition is a **broken** query - there's a **reason** why `only_full_group_by` is now the default in MySQL! Can you please provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML - better yet, put them into a fiddle (but be sure to keep them here also!). p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have provided a fiddle. Please look at the last line before the tags.

Comment: I put your fiddle into dbfiddle.uk - the fiddle of choice [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dc909da120f2a346366ae952e40192d5)! Perhaps you might like to replace your  one with this one?

Comment: Ok thanks! I have replaced it.

Comment: See my comment to Lennart's answer! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: That link was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems easiest to just add 12 hours to date_hour:

```
select name, DATE(DATE_ADD(date_hour,INTERVAL 12 hour)) as date_hr
     , avg(nor)
     , avg( case when not (validation = 1 and p_i > 0) then p_i end) as p_i
from report
group by name, DATE(DATE_ADD(date_hour,INTERVAL 12 hour))
order by name, DATE(DATE_ADD(date_hour,INTERVAL 12 hour));
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=145ebd218081fc67c70fd3f45cd61af1)

EDIT: Doing some experiments made me realize what might cause some  confusion. Look at your validation column:

```
`validation` enum('0','1') DEFAULT NULL,
```

This means that:

```
COUNT(1) WHERE validation = 0  => 0
COUNT(1) WHERE validation = 1  => 3
COUNT(1) WHERE validation = 2  => 3
```

Whereas

```
COUNT(1) WHERE validation = '0'  => 3
COUNT(1) WHERE validation = '1'  => 3
COUNT(1) WHERE validation = '2'  => 0
```

My rephrased query would be:

```
select name, DATE(DATE_ADD(date_hour,INTERVAL 12 hour)) as date_hr
     , avg(nor)
     , avg( case when (validation = '1' and p_i <> '0') then p_i end) as p_i
from report
group by name, DATE(DATE_ADD(date_hour,INTERVAL 12 hour))
order by name, DATE(DATE_ADD(date_hour,INTERVAL 12 hour));
```

Beware that avg of a string may give weird results. Finally, ENUM in MySQL is a very weird construction that I would try to avoid. You may be interested in the following observation:

[How does MariaDB handle ENUM types used in FOREIGN KEY constraints?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207540/how-does-mariadb-handle-enum-types-used-in-foreign-key-constraints/207541#207541)

[Updated Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d5368c8efa9117d5aa947460e658d34c)

Comment: I apologize if this is very stupid, but I don't understand `case when not (validation = 1 and p_i > 0)`? It seems to be the opposite of what I would like to do, but clearly works. @nbk suggested the same thing, so clearly there's something I do not know.

Comment: To be honest, when trying to implement your description I got different results than the expected output as stated in your question. @nbk's result matched the expected output, so I copied his expression and rephrased it a bit.

Comment: `select validation, p_i, case when not (validation = 1 and p_i > 0) then p_i end   from ( select 0 as validation, 4 as p_i union all select 0, 2 ) as t;` should give `4` and `2` for `p_i`. Is that what you meant  by `x`? So this expression seems to give the correct result.

Comment: @spheroid, I think I understand the origin of the confusion now. I have updated my answer, does that help?

Comment: This is it, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, try to fix your table so that you use appropriate types. Otherwise, you may end up with a lot of surprises. As an example: '.1' < '0'

Comment: Yes thank you, I will do that! I am going through the link you posted. Like you say, ENUM seems like something to avoid.

Comment: FWIW, the problem still exists in MySQL 8:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f8003355323db8dbb8b07ed1c7d8cb3 and MariaDB 10.5:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=8f8003355323db8dbb8b07ed1c7d8cb3

Comment: @Lennart - some people think that [ENUM](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)! :-) I happen to agree!

Comment: @Verace,Thanks for the link, I'll have a look eventhough I feel that what I know already is quite sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to understand what you are doing, but your logic for p_i is wrong. To get your wanted result:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     name, date_hr, AVG(nor), AVG(p_i)
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         name,
>             CASE
>                 WHEN TIME(date_hour) > '12:00:00' THEN DATE(date_hour) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
>                 ELSE DATE(date_hour)
>             END AS date_hr,
>             nor,
>             validation,
>             CASE
>                 WHEN validation = 1 AND p_i > 0 THEN NULL
>                 ELSE p_i
>             END AS p_i
>     FROM
>         report) z1
> GROUP BY name , date_hr;
> ```
>
> ```
> name | date_hr    | AVG(nor) | AVG(p_i)
> :--- | :--------- | -------: | -------:
> SYN  | 2018-02-03 |     18.5 |     null
> SYN  | 2018-02-04 |       10 |        3
> SYN  | 2020-04-07 |     14.5 |      3.5
> YRT  | 2020-04-06 |      136 |     null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=16253837f9ba0be9e074d0ceeb48d0e9)*